# Queremos um ambiente com a tag [.env]?

Tags: debate, tags

A tag [.env](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.env) doeu meus olhos quando vi. Não faz muito sentido ela, já que ela é uma coisa específica do framework Laravel.

Na minha humilde opinião, bastaria apenas a pergunta ter a tag [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) que o problema estava resolvido.

Deveria ser removida ou não?

Comment: Não é assim que faz pergunta sobre tag :P

Comment: Acho que .env não se refere apenas ao Laravel não.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas mesmo assim, é necessário?

Comment: Sinceramente não sei

Comment: Então talvez trocar o nome para uma que não se restrinja apenas ao laravel, tipo `local-enviroments`

Comment: @bfavaretto mesmo que não ainda sim a tag é um problema, justamente por poder ser ambigua. Eu sempre bato na 'tecla' "citar as tecnologias e evitar tags do tipo", tipo quando usam a tag [tag:sql], mas geralmente o problema é no PHP. Aliais esse tipo de problema é bem comum em diversas tags, talvez quando me sobrar um tempo eu venha com um *dossiê* de tags que considero problematicas.

Comment: @Maniero Não seja por isso, editei.

Comment: Vou dizer pra vocês, tem 3 perguntas nessa tag, se amanhã ela não estiver mais por aqui ninguém vai nem dar falta...

Comment: Será que não seria legal estabelecer um critério de que para uma tag ser criada ela deveria ao menos ter alguma descrição? Mesmo as que são auto explicativas deveriam ter descrição, porque as pessoas interpretam as coisas de formas diferentes, e a descrição serviria para esclarecer o uso da tags. Essa daí por exemplo, só é usada em 3 perguntas e nem descrição tem, ninguém sabe qual foi a real intenção ao cria-la.

Answer (score 5):

Como o bfavareto disse:

> Acho que .env não se refere apenas ao Laravel não.

Isto para mim já reforça a questão da tag [.env](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.env) ser um problema, independente de se usar <s>, e com todo respeito eu pessoalmente discordo da resposta [@WictorChaves](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7416/3635), tags são sim especificas por dois fatores:</s>

- Wiki de tag
- Como a comunidade lida com tags "compostas", como [android-webview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-webview)

> Na verdade **eu** entendi mal a resposta do Wictor, então estou "excluindo" essa parte, basicamente a sugestão da resposta dele foi o mesmo da **sugestão 1** que esta no final desta resposta também.

Se as tags fosse para ser usadas de forma composta criar uma pergunta assim com ambas tags: [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [webview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview) mesmo que pareça fazer sentido de primeira ainda sim não cobriria alguns.

Uma coisa que eu noto é que as pessoas simplesmente não entendem bem as tags, tags no site (seja SOen seja SOpt) tem "propósitos" e "ferramentas", como o já citado **Wiki de tag** e também temos para tags:

- Feeds (atom) de tag
- Observar tag (Watch) / Ignorar tag (ignore), exemplo:

  [image: ferramentas para tags do site]

Se a comunidade resolvesse que tags fossem ambíguas em uso como o já citado [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) + [webview](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webview), então eu desejasse seguir (via Feed ou Watch) as perguntas sobre WebView mas gostaria só de receber atualizações sobre android, menos iOS e WindowsPhone, dessa forma seria impossível diferenciar, e tornaria muito mais difícil "filtrar automaticamente".

A ideia de tags compostas (`android-webview`) ou não (`adroid`+`webview`) já foi debatido, tanto aqui no SOpt, quanto no chat, quanto no SOen, quase sempre a ideia que se chega é que as tags compostas acabam resolvendo melhor e não só pelas ferramentas, mas pelo Wiki de tag também, que geralmente (mesmo que alguns não se deem conta ainda disto) pode e as "muitas" vezes é usado para indicar tutoriais, como começar naquela tecnologia, links úteis e até história sobre a tag tecnologia da tag, se a tag for ambigua (servir para mais de um assunto) teriamos que gerar um Wiki enorme falando de tudo que aquilo aborda, o que do meu ponto de vista **não é o ideal**

---

### Sobre a tag [.env](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.env)

Como eu já [comentei](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7415/queremos-um-ambiente-com-a-tag-env?cb=1#comment28692_7415), mas talvez não consegui me fazer claro, a questão sobre a tag `.env` poder ser usada em mais de um lugar já mostra duas coisas:

- Ela é ambígua (mais de uma tecnologia a usa)
- Ela combinada com [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) não vai resolver o problema de quem usa Feed/Watch e muito **provavelmente não** vamos ter um "bom" Wiki sobre ela.

Por isso as minhas propostas/sugestões são:

### Sugestão 1

- Simplesmente matar a tag, pois raramente temos perguntas sobre isto, já que o .env é mais como um .ini e suas características estão atreladas a alguma outra tecnologia, ele não é como `yaml`, ele é algo bem mais simples (ao menos aonde vi sendo usado), a tag só [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) para o caso de perguntas ligadas ao .env dele já deve resolver.

### Sugestão 2

- Criar uma tag composta para cada tecnologia que tenha o seu próprio `.env`, por exemplo:

  [laravel-env](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-env), [docker-env](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-env) (não sei se isso "existe"), ou coisas do gênero

---

Quero reforçar um exemplo, aqui no SOpt usamos [composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer) para nos referirmos ao https://getcomposer.org/, mas no SOen é provavel que isto tenha causado algum problema, pois lá a tag foi convertida em sinonimo e a tag especifica é a [`composer-php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php), o que reforça que fazer algo como: `[php] + [composer]` pode parecer que resolve, mas que provavelmente gera confusão, ainda mais se tratando das ferramentas já citadas.

Comment: Concordo, o arquivo `.env` serve apenas para que uma biblioteca leia e carregue seu conteúdo nas variáveis de ambiente. É só pesquisar `dotenv` no Google que vem pacotes para npm, php, Ruby, etc...

Answer (score 3):

O problema desta tag é que ela se refere a um arquivo, e o escopo da tag é para categorizar, como a tag é referente a apenas um arquivo de uma tecnologia, a resposta pode ser referente a um arquivo de mesmo nome porem de outra tecnologia.

O Laravel tem o arquivo .env para algumas configurações, mas o Yowsup também tem este arquivo com a mesma nomenclatura, o problema é se existir uma pergunta referente ao Laravel e com a resposta referente ao Yowsup.

A existência da dúvida referente ao arquivo .env se deu graças ao seu formato, dando a entender que é uma extensão, como é o caso do html por exemplo, que neste caso pode sim, ser uma categoria, já que se referencia a um conjunto, mas o ".env" é apenas um arquivo.

Comment: Caro Wictor eu pessoalmente discordo, se isto que esta afirmando fosse certo as tags não teriam Wiki e também não seria comum o uso de tags como [tag:android-webview], bastaria adicionar as tags [tag:android] e [tag:webview], até parece fazer sentido, mas na maioria dos casos não, pois o Wiki por si só agrupa coisas especificas. Ao meu ver tags são sim especificas.

Comment: Mas quando você usa a tag, android-webview, já vem a cabeça aplicações webs rodando em um aplicativo, que pode sim ser um agrupamento, mas o .env é apenas um arquivo do Laravel, ou de outra tecnologia, é como se eu fizesse uma tag com o nome content_main.xml que é apenas um arquivo para desenvolver uma aplicação android.

Comment: Caro Wictor, justamente isso, acho que vocÊ não esta pegando o ponto que quero chegar, a questão é simplesmente que tags não são ambiguas, não são para serem usadas combinadas podendo dar a ideia de que uma tag pode ser usada para coisas diferente, houve casos no passado do soen e sopt e até discussões sobre usar de tal forma, mas isto claramente se tornou um problema com o tempo, principalmente pelo uso indevido e confuso que isto proporcionava. Vou tentar elaborar uma contra resposta mostrando os pontos da minha afirmação, acho que vai ficar mais claro para todos.

Comment: Tudo bem, irei aguardar, mas o que eu quis dizer é o seguinte, acredito que uma tag .env é incorreto, porque pode ser que sejam várias tecnologias que usam esta nomenclatura, o .env do Laravel é diferente do .env do Yowsup, só neste exemplo já temos o problema que esta tag pode causar.

Comment: Perai, li novamente a sua resposta, agora percebo que entendi errado a sua afirmação, na verdade concordo contigo, é que o começo do teu texto (por minha culpa) me confundiu mesmo, sim concordo contigo, a tag por si só é um problema. Edita a sua resposta por favor, assim eu posso reverter o downvote (downvotes só podem ser revertidos se tiver utrapassado o tempo limite se a resposta receber edição). +1

Comment: Resposta editada (y)